# Laurent series $f(z)=\frac{e^z}{z^2-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I have to found the Laurent Series of $f(z)=\frac{e^z}{z^2-1}$ on the annulus $0<|z|<1$. I'm not sure what to do here. I know I can expand the $e^z$:
$f(z)=\frac{1+z+z/2!..}{z^2-1}$, but I am not sure if this is the right approach.
I am also a little confused about the "on the annulus" part.

So my question is how to find the right series :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The reason why we need to consider two different "annuli" (I suppose you can call it area of convergence) is because the function has poles on the unit circle. One power series expansion is valid inside, but another one outside.

Answer (score 2):

An idea:

$$\frac{e^z}{z^2-1}=-e^z\frac1{1-z^2}=-\left(1+z+\frac{z^2}2+\frac{z^3}6+\ldots+\frac{z^k}{k!}+\ldots\right)\left(1+z^2+z^4+\ldots+z^{2k}+\ldots\right)=$$

$$=-\left(1+z+\frac32z^2+z^3+\frac32z^4+\ldots\right)$$

The above is valid for $\;|z|<1\;$, and observe we get a *power series*, as expected from an analytic function on $\;0<|z|<1\;$ . We cannot expand this annulus anymore as the function has two singular points on $\;|z|=1\;$ ...

In fact, the "annulus thing" is just for the purpose of considering a Laurent series. After the work above is done, we can see that taking off the point $\;z=0\;$ is moot and we can add it, working simply with $\;|z|<1\;$ .